# NPM: checkPermissions Missing write access to | Ionic 4 & Angular 8

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, command-line-interface

Hi guys i need an help: npm doesn't install any ionic plugin...the return after any installation is this:
(i need to install this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network)

Error on terminal vs code:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/xxxx/Documents/app/node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator
npm WARN The package @angular/compiler is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! path /Users/xxxx/Documents/app/node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno -62
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/Users/xxxx/Documents/app/node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxxx/.npm/_logs/2019-09-26T07_01_48_592Z-debug.log
```

I've installed cordova-pdf-generator and removed after.
I've tried to remove manually from node_modules folder, but anything i run npm i see this file :

So my package.json:

Package JSON:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "rasterizehtml": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

MY LOG:

```
26 warn The package @angular/compiler is included as both a dev and production dependency.
27 verbose stack Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/Users/xxxx/Documents/app/node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator'
28 verbose cwd /Users/xxxx/Documents/app
29 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
30 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
31 verbose node v10.12.0
32 verbose npm  v6.9.0
33 error path /Users/xxxx/Documents/app/node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator
34 error code ELOOP
35 error errno -62
36 error syscall access
37 error ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/Users/xxxx/Documents/app/node_modules/cordova-pdf-generator'
38 verbose exit [ -62, true ]
```

any solutions to re-enable installation plugin ? 
Thanks

Comment: try to delete your `node_module` folder and run command `npm i`.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib you're right! that works thanks

Answer (score 0):

close your `terminal`

then go to `terminal` ->
right click `run as administrator`

after that

- Delete `node_modules`

  npm install

for

```
IOS
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solved following steps:

> There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the
>   default directory that npm uses; for example, if you are sharing a
>   machine with other users.
>
> In this case, you can configure npm to use a different directory.
>
> Make a directory for global installations: 
>   `mkdir ~/npm-global`
>
> Configure npm to use the new directory path: 
>   `npm config set prefix '~/npm-global'`
>
> Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line: 
>   `export PATH=~/npm-global/bin:$PATH`
>
> Back on the command line, update your system variables: 
>   source ~/.profile; source ~/.bashrc

Reference: [NPM DOC](https://github.com/mixonic/docs.npmjs.com/blob/master/content/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.md)